# I need to get all the prime numbers from 1 to a large number?

Tags: java, math, primes

I need to create a program that can get all the prime numbers from 1 to a large number. I have a `getPrime` method which returns `true` if the number is prime or `false` if it is not prime. When I use this method and a while loop to get a list of prime numbers from 1 to a large number it keeps returning 24 then 4 then 5.the variable `end`, in code below is asked for in a prime class runner separately. Here is my code:

```
public class Prime 
{

    private long userNumber;
    private int numRoot;
    private int x;
    private boolean isPrime;
    private int factors;
    private long end;
    private int i;

    public void setUserNumber(long num)
    { 
       userNumber = num;
    }

    public void setEndNumber(long n)
    { 
        end = n;
    }

    public boolean getPrime()
    {
        numRoot = ((int)Math.sqrt(userNumber));


        for (x=2; x<=numRoot; x++)
        {
            if ((userNumber % x) == 0)
            {
                factors++;        
            }
        }

        if (factors >1) {
            isPrime = false;
        }
        else {
            isPrime = true;
        }
        return  isPrime;
    }  
    public void getPrimeList()
    {
        if(end < 2) {
            System.out.println("No prime numbers");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.printf("\nThe prime numbers from 1 to %d are: \n 2", end);
        Prime primeNum = new Prime();
        i = 3;
        while( i <= end )
        {
            userNumber = i;
            getPrime();
            if (isPrime == true)
            {
                System.out.println(userNumber);
            }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
 }
```

Comment: this shouldn't be under "javascript". The code you posted is written in java.

Comment: Google for "prime numbers".  There are tables online for the first 10K or so values.

Comment: You're never resetting the variable factors to 0.

Comment: do you work for the NSA?

Comment: [Here is a bunny with a pancake on its head!](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/007/445/pancake_bunny.jpg?1249339142)

Comment: RIP Original Pancake Bunny. The interwebz will know your presence forever. As for the question at hand, you know that setting a couple of breakpoints in your debugger can do wonders for letting you know whether the expected values of your variables match the actual values.

Comment: `1` is not a prime number.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - That depends on whose definitions you're using.  After all, the common definition is a number that can only be evenly divided by 1 and itself.

Comment: @HotLicks The general definition is that prime numbers have to be greater than 1, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number For hashCodes, you want a prime number greater than 2 ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey - But there are several definitions, varying as to whether 1 and 2 are included.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PrimeTest{
    private static final int MAX_NUM = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // your big number

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<MAX_NUM; i++) {
            if (isPrime(i)) {
                System.out.printf("Prime number %d\n", i);
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("There is %d prime numbers between %d and %d\n", count, 0, MAX_NUM);
    }


    public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
        if (number < 2) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i=2; i*i <= number; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (int i=2; i <= number/2; i++) {` this should actually be `for (int i=2; i*i <= number; i++) {`

Answer (score 0):

A prime number `p` should have zero factors between 2 and `sqrt(p)`, but you are allowing one here:

```
if (factors >1){
    isPrime = false;
}
```

In fact, there's no need to count factors at all, you can directly do

```
if ((userNumber % x) == 0) {
    return false; 
}
```

If you however need to count factors anyways, I would suggest setting `factors` explicitly to `0` at the start. It's not a good practice to rely on implicit initial values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using too many instance variables inside `getPrime`, causing you to unintentionally inherit state from previous iterations. More precisely, `factors` should be *reset* to `0` at the start of `getPrime`.

A better way to go about this is by making `x`, `numRoot`, `isPrime` and `factors` *local variables* of `getPrime`:

```
public boolean getPrime()
{
    int factors = 0;
    boolean isPrime;
    int numRoot = ((int) Math.sqrt(userNumber));

    for (int x=2; x<=numRoot; x++)
    {
        if ((userNumber % x) == 0)
        {
            factors++;        
        }
    }

    if (factors >1){
        isPrime = false;
    } else {
        isPrime = true;
    }
    return  isPrime;
}
```

You can go even further and make `userNumber` an *argument* of `getPrime`:

```
    public boolean getPrime(int userNumber)
    {
        // ...
```

and call it with:

```
while( i <= end )
{
            isPrime = getPrime(i);
    if (isPrime)
    {
        System.out.println(userNumber);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Two things to note:

- I removed the usage of `userNumber` inside `getPrimeList` completely, I simply use `i` instead.
- The `isPrime` could be removed as well if it's not needed elsewhere, simply use `if(getPrime(i)) { ... }` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getPrimes(int N) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) System.out.println(i);
    }
    System.out.println("These are all the prime numbers less than or equal to N.");
}

private boolean isPrime(int N) {
    if (N < 2) return false;
    for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(N); i++) {
        if (N % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below is written in C#, although it will work in Java with very little modification.
I use a long as the data type as you haven't been specific when you say "a large number".

```
    public static bool isPrime(long Number)
    {
        if (Number == 1) { return false; }
        int i = 2;
        while (i < Number)
        {
            if (Number % i++ == 0) { return false; }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

It can be applied like so, again this is C#, but will work in Java with little modification.

```
    while (i <= LARGE_NUMBER)
    {
        Console.Write((isPrime(i) ? i.ToString() + "\n" : ""));
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is the wrong solution for your task. The task is to find all primes from 2 to N, the appropriate algorithm is the **Sieve of Eratosthenes**. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18139477/3088138) for an epic rant discussing basics and optimizations of sieve algorithms.)

It is known that all primes are either 2,3,5,7,11,13 or of the form

```
30*k-13, 30*k-11, 30*k-7, 30*k-1, 30*k+1, 30*k+7, 30*k+11, 30*k+13,
```

for k=1,2,3,...

So you generate an array boolean isPrime[N+1], set all to true and for any candidate prime p of the form above, until p*p>N and if isPrime[p] is true, set all isPrime[k*p]=false for k=2,3,4,...N/p.

---

```
int N;
Boolean isPrime[] = new Boolean[N+6];

static void cross_out(int p) {
    for(int k=5*p, d=2; k<N; k+=d*p, d=6-d) {
         isPrime[k]=false;
    }
}

static void sieve() {
    for(int k=0; k<N; k+=6) {
        isPrime[k  ]=isPrime[k+2]=false;
        isPrime[k+3]=isPrime[k+4]=false;
        isPrime[k+1]=isPrime[k+5]=true;
    }
    for(int k=5, d=2; k*k<N; k+=d; d=6-d) {
        if(isPrime[k]) cross_out(k);
    }
}
```